# Material UI Autocomplete not able to access result from an Async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, material-ui

I am using Material UI Autocomplete to access the postcode using getZipCode function from 'use-places-autocomplete' which returns a promise. In the renderOption where I render the postcode in the `<li>` component I am not able to access the zipCode value which should have been calculated in the `async function getPostCode()` method. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const Places = () => {     
    return (
      <Autocomplete       
        options={data}                    
        getOptionLabel={(option) => typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.description}
        filterOptions={(x) => x}
        renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Location' />}
        onInputChange={(event, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        renderOption={(props, option) => {
          var zipCode='';
          async function getPostCode() {
            try {                                                       // zipcode is assigned here
              await getGeocode({placeId: option.place_id}).then(results => zipCode = getZipCode(results[0], true));              
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          }
          getPostCode();                   
          return (
            <li {...props} >             
                 {`${option.terms[0].value}, ${option.terms[1]?.value}, ${zipCode}`}
            </li>
          )
        }
        }
      />    

    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

It's totally wrong because the idea of `renderOptions` is for visual appearance change instead of logic management.

The best way would be to map options and fetch zipcodes for them before rendering and concat it with options or map somehow.

```
function Test() {
  const Places = () => {

      const [zipCodes, setZipCodes] = useState({});

      data.forEach((option) => {
        getGeocode({placeId: option.place_id}).then(results => setZipCodes({...zipCodes, [option]: getZipCode(results[0], true)}));
      });
    
      return (
        <Autocomplete
          options={data}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.description}
          filterOptions={(x) => x}
          renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Location' />}
          onInputChange={(event, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
          renderOption={(props, option) => 
            return (
              <li {...props}>
                   {`${option.terms[0].value}, ${option.terms[1]?.value}, ${zipCodes[option] || 'Loading...'}`}
              </li>
            )
          }
          }
        />

      );
    }
}
```

Comment: @ihomillion Thanks for the quick response but with your solution I am getting the dropdown to refresh uncontrollably with the postcode number changing between the different locations.

Comment: @Pasang in that case you can concat all requests into one and update zipCodes only once when ALL promises resolved. 

Something like:

Promise.all(data.map((option) => getGeocode({placeId: option.place_id})).then((...response) => // handle array of responses);

The general idea is to fetch all the data before start rendering of your component. 

if it is crucial to display the information of zipcodes - show "loading" and don't remember Autocomplete at all, while zipcodes are fetching